# Pygame Sprite group stating that it has no sprites in it but also showing that it contains over 1000

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Using pygame to create a maze algorithm analyzer and I have a collide_with_walls function that tests if the bot will collide with the wall. For the exact same function in different bots, there has been no problem, however for the bot I am making now, the "Walls" group is saying it is empty (using `.has()`) but it also appears with nearly 2,000 sprites (using `.sprites()`). I'm not sure where the difference could be or how to fix this.

```py
    def collide_with_walls(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        print("RANDO WALL" + str(self.game.walls))
        print(self.game.walls.has())
        print(self.game.walls.sprites())
        for wall in self.game.walls:
            print(wall)
            print(wall.rect.x)
            print(wall.rect.y)
            if wall.x == self.x + dx and wall.y == self.y + dy:
                return True
            return False
```

Problematic collide function, checking if the bots x,y will match up with any of the walls x, y

```py
class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

Wall class where the wall group is initialized

```py
    def collide_with_walls(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        for wall in self.game.walls:
            if wall.x == self.x + dx and wall.y == self.y + dy:
                return True
        return False
```

Working collide function from another class for reference.

```py
print(self.game.walls.has())
```

Outputs False

```py
print(self.game.walls.sprites())
```

Outputs 673 lines of text containing each individual wall in the game.

Edit: wall.x and wall.y only print out 0.

Answer (score 1):

[`has(*sprites) -> bool`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.has) test whether all the given *Sprites* are contained in the *Group*. If you call this method without any argument the method returns `False`. This means `self.game.walls.has()` is useless, because it returns always `False`.

You can use [`bool(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) or [`len(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to test whether the *Group* contains *Sprites* (see [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.has)):

```py
print(bool(self.game.walls))
```

```py
print(len(self.game.walls))
```

---

Example:

```py
sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
group = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite)

print(group.has())
print(group.has(sprite))
print(bool(group))
print(len(group))
```

Output:

> ```
> False
> True
> True
> 1
> ```

Comment: Ok I tried that, the boolean returns True. So if there are sprites in the group, what could be causing the x and y to consistently return 0 when it works on the other classes?

Comment: @GavinTynan Is that a new question? I can't guess. Your question does not provide enough information. `wall.x` and `wall.y` are set in the constructor. What is `self.x` and `self.y` in the constructor? Note, `wall.rect.x` is not `wall.x`

Comment: Yes my bad, technically a different question. No problem.